# How to Access Indices of ArrayList Inside Another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on an recursive programming assignment, and I'm trying to find out how to loop and get values of an ArrayList inside of a bigger ArrayList. I found that others have asked this question before, but it is still not very clear how this can be done precisely.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> Array1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Array 1: [0][1][0][0][1]

    Array1.add("0");
    Array1.add("1");
    Array1.add("0");
    Array1.add("0");
    Array1.add("1");

    ArrayList<String> Array2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Array 2: [1][0][0][1][0]

    Array2.add("1");
    Array2.add("0");
    Array2.add("0");
    Array2.add("1");
    Array2.add("0");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Array3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    // Array 3: [Array1][Array2]

    Array3.add(Array1);
    Array3.add(Array2);

// Now Find every indices or occurrences in Array2 where value is "1"

    for (ArrayList<String> Outer : Array3) {
        for (String inner : Outer) {
            if (str.equals("1")) {
                // Get all indices where "1" is found inside Array2 ?

            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So I have Array3 that stores **Array1** and **Array2**, and what I want to do is loop through Array3, find Array2 and indices in Array2 where value is "1".

The problem with the loop in in this code is that it loops through all values in Array1 and Array2 whereas I'm just trying to find the values inside Array2.

Comment: Find Array2 how? By index, or by reference?

Comment: `str.equals` or `inner.equals` ?

Comment: @brazjul, kindly find an alternative approach of constructing ArrayLists in my code solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
for (ArrayList<String> Outer : Array3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Outer.size(); i++) {
        if (Outer == Array2 && Outer.get(i).equals("1")) {
            // The index is stored in 'i'
        }
    }
}
```

Although I don't understand why you want to iterate through both `ArrayList`s when you're only looking for the indices in the latter.

It would be easier to just iterate through `Array2`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array2.size(); i++) {
    if (Array2.get(i).equals("1")) {
        // The index is stored in 'i'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Essentially what I want to do is get from Array3 -> to Array2 --> and find indices 0 and 3 which happens to be the two indices where value "1" is found

Comment: @brazjul You're welcome!  I can't say that I understand your motive, but this solution will work, and the overhead depends on the size of `Array1`.  Remember that you can upvote/accept any answers that help you on StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

This is what your main should look like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> Array1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Array 1: [0][1][0][0][1]

    Array1.add("0");
    Array1.add("1");
    Array1.add("0");
    Array1.add("0");
    Array1.add("1");

    ArrayList<String> Array2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Array 2: [1][0][0][1][0]

    Array2.add("1");
    Array2.add("0");
    Array2.add("0");
    Array2.add("1");
    Array2.add("0");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Array3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    // Array 3: [Array1][Array2]

    Array3.add(Array1);
    Array3.add(Array2);

// Now Find every indices or occurrences in Array2 where value is "1"
    int i = 0;
    for (String  s: Array3.get(1)) {

            if (s.equals("1")) {
                // Get all indices where "1" is found inside Array2 ?

                    System.out.println(i);
         }
            i++;
      }
   }
```

If you only want to find in the 2nd ArrayList loop only thorough it. Get if from Array3 via get function

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Integer>` as a good coding approach.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> Array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0,1,0,0,1));
    ArrayList<Integer> Array2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,0,0,1,0));
    // Quick way to clear ArrayList

    List<ArrayList<Integer>> Array3 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    Array3.add(Array1);
    Array3.add(Array2);

    for (ArrayList<Integer> al : Array3) {
        if (al != Array2) { // check only for ArrayList2
            continue;
        }
        for (Integer I : al) { // Iterate ArrayList2
            if (I.equals(1)) {
                // 1 is stored in ArrayList2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the problem that I'm working on, I'm storing my ArrayList as string, because I'm working on a separate code that parse string data from a file into a large array, breaks that array into multiple arrays and tries to find certain values inside those smaller arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding the count (occurances) of "1" from `Array2`, it is a simple solution from Java8 as shown below with inline comments:

```
Array3.stream().
    skip(1). //skip the first array
    flatMap(List::stream). //get the stream of elements from second array
    filter(value ->  value.equals("1")).//check which elements are equal to 1
    count();//count how many
```

Also, I strongly suggest you **follow Java naming standards strictly** (refer [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)) like variable names must be starting with lowercase (like `array3`, not `Array3`) so that it will be easier to read and follow your code.

Comment: OP is trying to get the index of each "1", not the amount of them.

Comment: he says occurrences as well

Answer (score 0):

```
for (List<Long> range : queries) {

        long l = range.get(0);
        long r = range.get(1);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.